# Can't login to django admin with correct credentials

Tags: python-3.x, django

I can't login to my django admin side even after puting correct credentials.
It gives me the error... "*Please enter the correct email and password of a staff account. Note that both fields may be case sensitive.*"

And yes, the credentials is a  superuser, a staff and active.
I use a custom authentication backend and my version is Django 2.2

Please help me.

UPDATE:

this is my authentication backend

```
    class MyAuthenticationBackend:
        def authenticate(self, request=None, email=None, password=None, designation=None):
            try:
                user = MyUser.objects.get(email=email, designation=designation)
            except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
                return None
            else:
                if check_password(password, user.password):
                    return user
            return None

        def get_user(self, user_id):
            try:
                return MyUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
                return None
```

Comment: Can you share the authentication backend? How do you *create* users?

Comment: I create users through a form on my front end. I can log in well from my designed front end and when logged in, django admin logs me in too.  The same login credentials that the django admin login refuses to authenticate

Answer (score 0):

if u have just started the project, u can run `django-admin flush` it will clean up the database and then u can create superuser again

Comment: Does that solve it? Cleaning up my database. I'm just confused.

Comment: it will delete entire database, including data about superuser. if u r cool with that. after u can run migrations and create a new super user

Comment: Giorgi, thanks but i have gone deep into this. I will consider this if i can't seem to find any other solution.

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tyBEsHSv7w&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&index=12)   this might help